# How to make Error 'Variable' is not defined work?

Tags: python, function, import, reload, maya

Through a button, (itself called by an other python script), I try to run a script named Python_Chara.
When i launch it directly, it works. But through my button I have the error :

```
'Chara' is not define...
```

this is the code :

```
cmds.nodeIconButton(style='iconOnly', c="Chara()")
def Chara():
    import Python_Chara
    reload (Python_Chara)
```

Any ideas ? I've tried different way but nothing works it …

Comment: you have to define function `Chara()` before you use in button. So maybe you have to only put it in different order.

Comment: Also, the first time you call the function, the script will run twice

Comment: I tried different order but it was not working..

Answer (score 0):

in your Chara file, you should encapsulate what you want to do inside a def, so in in your **Python_Chara.py** :

```
def doIt(*args):
    print('doing something I will want to do in my ui')
```

in your other script, you do :

```
import Python_Chara
cmds.nodeIconButton(style='iconOnly', c=Python_Chara.doIt)
```

Comment: Thanks DrWeeny for you reply ! Unfortunatly it's not working. # AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'doIt' #     But your solution sounds correct. I justy don't put something for (*args) in your exemple.               I'm just like :   def doIt(*args):
 cmds.matchTransform()                                                                                   about the rest, everything is similar...

Comment: Did you reload Python_Chara after adding a doIt def in it ?

Comment: I did yes, with no success... since last day i'm wondering if it's not because my button is called from an other script.   A script call this button>this button call>Python_Chara

Comment: Could you give us an example of your two files ? So we can see where could be your error ?

Comment: import maya.cmds as cmds
import sys
sys.path.append("Y:/000_Scripts")
import Python_winButton
reload (Python_winButton)
#This is the first script

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import os, sys
import maya.cmds as cmds 
import pymel.core as pm

dataPathFile = ""
sys.path.append("Y:/000_Scripts")

NBI = 'Y:/000_Scripts/icones'
TabShelf = pm.language.melGlobals['gShelfTopLevel'] #####different part with creation of the window with button#####   import Python_MatchTransform
cmds.nodeIconButton( style='iconOnly', c=Python_MatchTransform.Match, i=NBI+"/matchtransform.png", ann='Match Transform',ua=True)

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import os, sys
import maya.cmds as cmds 



def Match(*args):
 cmds.matchTransform()
 print "Au pied!"   #and the last one

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the usage of import/reload statement. Try for the moment to make everything work inside one script. Once you are satisfied and you can launch this script, you will be able to split the functions

Comment: I've edit your post to have components of your script

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWGAV.png)

this are my codes. the second one is a window with differents buttons wich have the same problemes